# Incorrect syntax when using sys.dm_exec_sql_text - SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Running this to look at some of the statements that have been run against a SQL Server 2005 instance.  Not sure why it gives me an error complaining about the syntax.

> Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Code:

```
SELECT TOP 1000
    dest.text,
    deqs.last_execution_time
FROM    
    sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY 
    sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.[sql_handle]) AS dest   
ORDER BY 
    deqs.last_execution_time DESC;
```

Comment: There has to be something else in your code. I ran your query (which looked fine to me) against 2005, 2008, 2012 and 2014 instances and it worked perfectly each time. There is obviously some other code you are trying to execute.

Comment: Nope, since I selected another DB within SSMS and the query ran fine.

Comment: Can you try to isolate the problem. Run each dmv on its own. And also find out exactly which '.' it's referring to.

Comment: Its complaining about the line that is doing the cross_apply

Comment: Can you test this: declare @plan_handle varbinary(6) = 0x06000100502A82123076D5892F00000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000; SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(@plan_handle); Obviously, substitute a valid plan handle.

Comment: I can query sys.dm_exec_sql_text with individual plan_handle values, however I think I might have stumbled upon the issue.  I checked the DB compatibility level and someone had set to SQL 2000
See this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e8771fc4-fc15-43cc-a396-a87149e8d32c/sysdmexecsqltext-not-working-in-standard-edition?forum=transactsql

Comment: Ha. Was about to suggest you look at compatibility mode. I figured it would be set to 2000 which would cause that to fail.